# Como borrar Imagenes o Videos guardados en MEDIA_URL usando Django

Tags: django, django-models

En la base de datos se guardan los datos con la dirección que esta en MEDIA_URL y se borran perfectamente ya que lo único que guarda es la dirección,pero  el problema esta en que los ficheros que se guardaron anteriormente en MEDIA_URL, no se borran se mantienen, necesito alguna idea de como poder borrarlos cuando se elimine la tupla que corresponde con su dirección física.

Estoy intentando hacerlo usando señalesy tengo el codigo asi

models.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete, post_delete
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
import os

class Video(models.Model):
filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
dueño = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos')
docfile = models.FileField(upload_to='video/%Y/%m/%d',
                           validators=[FileValidator(allowed_mimetypes=('video/avi', 'video/mp4'),
                                                     max_size=50 * 1024 * 1024)])
descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s ' % (self.filename)

@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Video)
def _videos_delete(sender, instance, using, **kwargs):
    file_path = settings.MEDIA_URL + str(instance.docfile)
    print(file_path)
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        os.remove(file_path)
```

pero sigue sin eliminarme el archivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar [os.remove()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) pasándole la ruta completa donde está el archivo.

En tu caso, parece que usas MEDIA_URL y esto probablemente no sea una ruta completa a la ubicación del archivo que queremos borrar.

Si en lugar de MEDIA_URL usamos MEDIA_ROOT solucionamos el problema

```
settings.py

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
MEDIA_URL = '/documentos/' #carpeta del servidor donde almacenaremos los documentos
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'documentos') # ruta completa en el servidor hasta la carpeta documentos
```

Luego puedes cambiar `MEDIA_URL` por `MEDIA_ROOT` cuando construyes tu `file_path`

En cualquier caso, comprueba pasandole directamente una ruta de achivo de este modo

```
os.remove(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT+'resto_de_ruta_incluyendo_el_nombre_de_archivo'))
```

Comment: Podrías ser más explicito donde utilizaría esto

Comment: actualize mi pregunta y estoy intentando como me dices usando os.renove() y ya revise la ruta y es la correcta pero no se elimina

Comment: Acabo de editar la respuesta, según lo que indicas, compruebalo, creo que te funcionará.

Answer (score 0):

Manejar archivos en Django es bastante fácil: puedes agregarlos a un modelo con solo una línea (para un repaso de los modelos de Django, puedes consultar nuestro artículo sobre manejo de marcos de datos web), y el framework lo hará todo por ti - validaciones, carga, verificación de tipos. Incluso servirlos requiere muy poco esfuerzo.

Sin embargo, hay una cosa que Django ya no hace a partir de la versión 1.3: borrar automáticamente los archivos de un modelo cuando se elimina la instancia.

Hay muchas buenas por las cuales se tomó esta decisión: en ciertos casos  este comportamiento era propenso a la pérdida de datos, y además es lo suficientemente lento como para que penalice al tiempo de respuesta de nuestra aplicación. Además, soluciones Cloud como las de Google o Amazon no nos van a dar demasiados problemas con exceso de ficheros. Pero claro, a veces usamos una VPS y el espacio es limitado.

Hay varias posibles soluciones para eliminar esos desagradables archivos no utilizados:

Una posible solución es crear un comando personalizado como este:

```
import os

from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.apps import apps
from django.db.models import Q
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import FileField


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = "This command deletes all media files from the MEDIA_ROOT directory which are no longer referenced by any of the models from installed_apps"

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
    all_models = apps.get_models()
    physical_files = set()
    db_files = set()

    # Get all files from the database
    for model in all_models:
        file_fields = []
        filters = Q()
        for f_ in model._meta.fields:
            if isinstance(f_, FileField):
                file_fields.append(f_.name)
                is_null = {'{}__isnull'.format(f_.name): True}
                is_empty = {'{}__exact'.format(f_.name): ''}
                filters &amp;= Q(**is_null) | Q(**is_empty)
        # only retrieve the models which have non-empty, non-null file fields
        if file_fields:
            files = model.objects.exclude(filters).values_list(*file_fields, flat=True).distinct()
            db_files.update(files)

    # Get all files from the MEDIA_ROOT, recursively
    media_root = getattr(settings, 'MEDIA_ROOT', None)
    if media_root is not None:
        for relative_root, dirs, files in os.walk(media_root):
            for file_ in files:
                # Compute the relative file path to the media directory, so it can be compared to the values from the db
                relative_file = os.path.join(os.path.relpath(relative_root, media_root), file_)
                physical_files.add(relative_file)

    # Compute the difference and delete those files
    deletables = physical_files - db_files        
    if deletables:
        for file_ in deletables:
            os.remove(os.path.join(media_root, file_))

        # Bottom-up - delete all empty folders
        for relative_root, dirs, files in os.walk(media_root, topdown=False):
            for dir_ in dirs:
                if not os.listdir(os.path.join(relative_root, dir_)):
                    os.rmdir(os.path.join(relative_root, dir_))
```

Hay otra opción más compleja de implementar: usar señales.

Cuando se elimina la instancia del modelo al que pertenece el archivo, aquí simplemente podemos usar la señal post_delete, que asegurará que la instancia ya haya sido eliminada de la base de datos con éxito. El código para esta parte es bastante sencillo:

```
from django.db.models import FileField
from django.db.models.signals import post_delete, post_save, pre_save
from django.dispatch.dispatcher import receiver

LOCAL_APPS = [
    'my_app1',
    'my_app2',
    '...'
]

def delete_files(files_list):
    for file_ in files_list:
        if file_ and hasattr(file_, 'storage') and hasattr(file_, 'path'):
            # this accounts for different file storages (e.g. when using django-storages)
            storage_, path_ = file_.storage, file_.path
            storage_.delete(path_)

@receiver(post_delete)
def handle_files_on_delete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # presumably you want this behavior only for your apps, in which case you will have to specify them
    is_valid_app = sender._meta.app_label in LOCAL_APPS
    if is_valid_app:
        delete_files([getattr(instance, field_.name, None) for field_ in sender._meta.fields if isinstance(field_, FileField)])
```

Esta útima solución es más elegante pero tiene un inconveniente: no tiene en cuenta las múltiples referencias al mismo archivo (aunque, a menos que no estés modificando directamente tu base de datos, esto nunca debería suceder).

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia soy nuevo en Django actualmente para eliminar utilizo o el sitio admin o la clase genérica DeleteView  donde pondría el código a me dices

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres eliminar desde la acción de un botón llamando a un view, puedes hacerlo con MEDIA_ROOT pero puede que necesites limpiar la ruta. Acá un ejemplo de un proyecto con un modelo "Pelicula" con un campo de imagen.Considera que mi ruta de almacenamiento es /media/peliculas/mi_imagen.jpg:

```
#imports necesarios para el ejemplo
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
import os

def eliminarpeli(request,id):
    #obteniedo la pelicula por id
    peli=get_object_or_404(Pelicula,id=id)
    
    #separa cada directorio en una lista para sacar los / 
    rutapartes=(peli.imagen.url).split("/")
    #mi lista queda asi ['', 'media', 'peliculas', 'mi_imagen.jpg']

    #crear la ruta faltante cambiando / por \\ como el media_root 
    #y no considerando el index 0 y 1 de la lista
    rutaok="\\"+str(rutapartes[2])+"\\"+str(rutapartes[3])
    
    #eliminando con la ruta correcta
    os.remove(os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+rutaok))

    #luego eliminar y redirigir
    peli.delete()

    return redirect(to="peliculas")
```

Probado y funcionando con django 3.2.4. Considera que la vista recibe un id en la llamada.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes sobreescribir el método delete en Models.py dentro de la Clase

```
def delete (self, *args, **kwargs):
   
    if os.path.isfile(self.imagen.path):
         os.remove(self.imagen.path)                    
        
    
    super(Incidencia,self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```